# URL not pulling the index page

Tags: html, mysql

Any ideas to why when I go to my site URL it's not pulling the index page? The index page is in the root directory. This was working before but for some reason it has stopped unexpectedly.

devoffpod.purplebottlemedia.com  this should pull the site up but doesn't unless I specify the /index.html at the end.

Comment: Maybe because: _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/content/58/8773958/html/devoffpod/index.php on line 8_ ???

Comment: I fixed it. I just had to change the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Your default document settings are set to load index.php either before or instead index.html. You'll need to change that. If you are in a shared hosting environment, look at the community help and support section. If you are hosting this yourself in Windows, open IIS and then default document. IIS allows multiple default documents, so if you want index.html to load instead of index.php, make sure index.html is at the top of the list. (Or just before index.php)

I am not sure how to do it on a Linux based server or Apache, but I am sure there are plenty of online forms for changing the default document settings.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the file name. This is an interesting piece of knowledge. Thanks for sharing this.